# SVG marker on Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

Using Google Maps API v3, my ultimate intent is to create an arrow of a given length and angle, but for now, I am trying to create an SVG marker. I am using the [Rich Market utility](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/) and the [jquery.svg plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). The following code creates the `div`, but doesn't create the SVG. Suggestions? (I am not wedded to these libraries, but these are what I found so far).

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, marker;
    function drawCircle(svg) { 
        svg.circle(15, 15, 10, {fill: 'none', stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 3});  
    }

    function div() {
        var m = document.createElement('DIV');
        m.innerHTML = '<div class="arrow"></div>';
        $('.arrow').svg({onLoad: drawCircle});
        return m;
    }

    function init() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 1,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        marker = new RichMarker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 50),
            draggable: true,
            flat: true,
            anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
            content: div()
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="map"></div></body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `div()` function. Calling `$('.arrow')` doesn't match the div that is being created because it hasn't been attached to the DOM node tree yet. You have to call it after the marker has been created.

Remove `$('.arrow').svg({onLoad: drawCircle});` from `div()` function and call it later.

```
function div() {
   var m = document.createElement('DIV');
   m.innerHTML = '<div class="arrow"></div>';
   return m;
}
```

I guess the best way is to add listener for map's idle event at the end of `init()` function.

```
function init() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 1,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });

   marker = new RichMarker({
          map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 50),
      draggable: true,
      flat: true,
      anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
      content: div()
   });

   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
      $('.arrow').svg({onLoad: drawCircle});
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected. However, I realized I should have asked the real question, which I have now done so at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465191/creating-an-svg-marker-on-click-event]