# creating an SVG marker on click event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

[Now that I can actually create an SVG marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462563/svg-marker-on-google-maps-v3)  here is my vision: The user clicks on the map, the click fires an Ajax query which retrieves "length" and "angle" values from a remote server, and using those values, and SVG arrow of the given lenght and angle is drawn at the click.

The Ajax part is easy, and once I have a length and angle, I can figure out the SVG syntax for an arrow. For now, I am trying to create the "click and create a random arrow". The code below kinda works. An arrow gets created at the "previous" click. That is, when I click on point 1, nothing happens. Then, when I click on point 2, an arrow is created at point 1, and so on for point(n-1) where n is the nth click.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.quiver {width: 50px; height: 50px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;

        function div() {
            var m = document.createElement('DIV');
            m.innerHTML = '<div class="quiver"></div>';
            return m;
        }

        function init() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(43, -89),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
                var marker = new RichMarker({
                    map: map,
                    position: event.latLng,
                    draggable: true,
                    flat: true,
                    anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
                    content: div()
                });

                $('.quiver').svg({
                    onLoad: function(svg) {
                        svg.line(
                            Math.random()*49, Math.random()*49, Math.random()*49, Math.random()*49,  
                            {stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 2}
                        );
                    }
                });
            });

            /*
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
                $('.quiver').svg({onLoad: drawArrow});
            });
            */
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462563/svg-marker-on-google-maps-v3). When you are calling

```
$('.quiver').svg({
    onLoad: function(svg) {
        ...
    }
});
```

in the click event listener, the marker that's being created hasn't been attached to the DOM node tree yet. Nice reading about synchronization and timing in JavaScript [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/timing-and-synchronization-in-javascript/).

The (n-1)-th arrow is rendered because the jQuery `$('.quiver')` command selects all elements with quiver class (that's n-1 elements, the n-th isn't present in the DOM node tree yet) and only the (n-1)-th is applicable for the svg code.

Unfortunately, the map's `idle` event (or any other event in Google Maps API v3) won't help it this case.

I guess there are 2 solutions to the problem:

One solution is to target the created HTML element with jQuery directly in the click event listener.

```
$(marker.content).find('.quiver').svg({
      onLoad: function(svg) {
          svg.line(
              Math.random()*49, Math.random()*49,
              Math.random()*49, Math.random()*49,
              {stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 2}
          );
       }
});
```

The second solution is not to use jQuery svg plugin, but rather create the svg directly in `div()` function.

```
function div() {
    var m = document.createElement('DIV');
    m.innerHTML = '<div class="quiver"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">' +
                  '<line x1="' + Math.random()*49 + '" y1="' + Math.random()*49 + '" ' +
                  'x2="' + Math.random()*49 + '" y2="' + Math.random()*49 + '" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"/></svg></div>';
    return m;
}
```

and delete the jQuery `$('.quiver').svg(...);` command in the click event listener.

Comment: Thanks. I was quite hoping to hide the complicatedness of SVG via jquery.svg, however, your suggestion 2 seems to work most efficiently for me for now. I believe suggestion 1 above would find *all* the markers in the html div and draw them, not as efficient as the other option.

Comment: The first suggestion targets only the newly created marker. $(marker.content) applies jQuery only to the html elements in marker.content (although marker.content might not be attached to the document yet). Since there are only two divs in marker.content, it should be almost as efficient as the second suggestion.