# How to add the svg code in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

I had a Blinking SVG code :  http://jsfiddle.net/Muthukumaru/n4d80zLd/

I am trying to add this SVG code to the Google maps to the particular pointer so that that particular marker do blink
I am new to the Google maps API , How to add the SVG code to the Google maps Code :

This is the Code of the Google Maps :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
                            ['STHOWBGA01_ATIF_RNID_L015',24.31026,93.56268],
                            ['GWTRGOK004_BILF_RNOD_L023',23.70692,91.27397],
                            ['GWTRBLWBN1_BILF_RNOD_L038',24.0179,91.4529],
                            ['SJOWKHL007_ATIF_RNOD_L012',25.35197,92.3723],
                            ['TTINNMSAI4_VIOF_RNID_L011',27.66616,95.87926],
                            ['SIMWUKHRL5_VIOF_RNID_L061',25.12267,94.36558],
                            ['SDIMZLUKI3_BILF_RNOD_L035',25.63658,93.64943]

            ];

    var lat_center = 24.31026,
        long_center = 93.56268;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_center, long_center),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i, text;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({

          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map

      });

      text = locations[i][0];

      if(locations[i][1] === lat_center && locations[i][2] === long_center) {

          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);

        marker.setIcon('https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png');
      }

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, text) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(text);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, text));
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I had passed the particular center marker with link png image : 
https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png

Instead of png image link , I want to pass the SVG code from JSfiddle that I provided above: 
can any one please help ,

Thanks

**NEW CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/search.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
b{
color:red;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

                        <?php
                                    include_once('connection.php');
                                    $con=SQL_CONNECT();

                                    $COMMAND="select unique(SITEID) from LATLONG";
                                    $stid = oci_parse($con, $COMMAND);
                                    $res=oci_execute($stid);
                                    echo "var availableTags = [ ";
                                    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid))
                                    {
                                       echo '"'.$row['SITEID'].'",';
                                    }
                                    echo "]";
                                    oci_close($con);

                            ?>



        $('#site').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open: function (e, ui) {
            var acData = $(this).data('autocomplete');
            acData
                .menu
                .element
                .find('a')
                .each(function () {
                    var me = $(this);
                    var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
                    me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b>$1</b>'));
                });
        }
    });


        //  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


        $("#butn").click(function(){
                var sitename=$("#site").val();

                if(sitename.length==0)
                {
                alert("please enter text");
                }
                else
                {   

                        $("#fetch").load('one_marker.php',{sitename:sitename},function(res){

                });
                }
        });


});

</script>
</head>

<body id='tableb'>
<table  align="center" id='tables'>
<tr><td>ENTER TEXT: </td><td><input type="text" id="site" name="sitename"  placeholder="Sitename"><div id="site_error"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input style="cursor:pointer" type="button" id="butn" value="submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="content" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="fetch"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The variable which i get the from the auto complete will pass through ajax call : **blink_php.php**

please check this page :

```
<?php 
    include_once('connection.php');

        $conn=SQL_CONNECT();

        $sitename=$_POST['sitename'];

        $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM latlong where SITEID like '%$sitename%'");

        $res=oci_execute($stid);    

            while($data = oci_fetch_array($stid))
            {  ?>

                    <div id="lati_center" style="display: none;">
                                    <?php 
                                        echo htmlspecialchars($data['LAT']);
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                    <div id="longi_center" style="display: none;">
                                    <?php 
                                        echo htmlspecialchars($data['LON']);
                                    ?>
                                </div>

        <?php           
        }
    oci_close($conn);
?> 

<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 

  <style>

  #map {
  margin:20px auto;
}
.reddot{

    width:66px;
    height:66px;
    position:absolute
}
.locater{
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 17px;
}
.mark{
    fill: none;
    stroke: #FF9100;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
}


</style>

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
                            <?php
                                            include_once('connection.php');

                                                    $con=SQL_CONNECT();

                                                    $COMMAND="select * from LATLONG";

                                                    $stid = oci_parse($con, $COMMAND);

                                                    $res=oci_execute($stid);

                                                    $len = "select count(*) from latlong";

                                                    $len_c = oci_parse($con, $len);
                                                    $res_c=oci_execute($len_c);

                                                    $i=0;

                                                    while ($data = oci_fetch_array($stid))
                                                    {       
                                                        if($i==$len - 1)
                                                        {   
                                                            echo "['<b>".$data['SITEID']."</b><br>".$data['ADDRESS']."</br>',".$data['LAT'].",".$data['LON']."]" ;

                                                        }else{

                                                            echo "['<b>".$data['SITEID']."</b><br>".$data['ADDRESS']."</br>',".$data['LAT'].",".$data['LON']."]," ;
                                                        }
                                                        $i++;   
                                                    }
                                                    oci_close($con);

                                            ?>


    ];

  var div_lat = document.getElementById("lati_center");

            var lat_center = div_lat.textContent;

      var div_lon = document.getElementById("longi_center");

            var long_center = div_lon.textContent;


            alert(div_lat+","+div_lon)


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_center, long_center),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i, text;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({

          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map

      });

      text = locations[i][0];

      if(locations[i][1] === lat_center && locations[i][2] === long_center) {
       // marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
        marker.setIcon('https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png');

        map.Overlay= new google.maps.OverlayView();

        map.Overlay.center_ = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_center, long_center);
        map.Overlay.reddot_ =  '<div id="reddot" class="reddot" style="position:relative;"><svg class="marker" height="66" width="66"><circle cy="33" cx="33" class="mark" r="25"><set id="show" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible" begin="0s; hide.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/><set id="hide" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden" begin="show.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/></circle><img src="" class="locater"></svg></div>';

        map.Overlay.draw = function () {
            var pixelposition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.center_);
            jQuery('#reddot').css({top:(pixelposition.y-50), left:(pixelposition.x-33)});

        };

        map.Overlay.onAdd=function() {
          var self=this;
          jQuery(self.getPanes().markerLayer).append(self.reddot_);
        };

        map.Overlay.setMap(map);

      }

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, text) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(text);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, text));
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Check this  question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462563/svg-marker-on-google-maps-v3

Comment: I had checked, but the code is different can you please provide me the link of jsfiddle

Comment: I would, but I'm working now, that link is the only help I can provide at this moment, if you havn't fixed it later I can come back and see if I can help more

Comment: K, I will try...If i can't will ping you..

Comment: Sorry dude ,I tried a lot not able to get getting Richmarker is not defined error is coming .. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an SVG element as marker Icon. What you can do is mimic the behavior of google.maps.Marker using an [google.maps.OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayView) element.

For example:

```
    map.Overlay= new google.maps.OverlayView();

    map.Overlay.center_ = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_center, long_center);
    map.Overlay.reddot_ =  '<div id="reddot" class="reddot" style="position:relative;"><svg class="marker" height="66" width="66"><circle cy="33" cx="33" class="mark" r="25"><set id="show" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible" begin="0s; hide.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/><set id="hide" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden" begin="show.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/></circle><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png" class="locater"></svg></div>';

    map.Overlay.draw = function () {
        var pixelposition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.center_);
        jQuery('#reddot').css({top:(pixelposition.y-50), left:(pixelposition.x-33)});

    };

    map.Overlay.onAdd=function() {
      var self=this;
      jQuery(self.getPanes().markerLayer).append(self.reddot_);
    };

    map.Overlay.setMap(map);
```

**See the working example at: http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/9e08b294d3bd7ce09220**

(I used jQuery to append the SVG to the markerLayer pane, but you can do that with raw js too)

Comment: Hi, amen Is it possible to change the circle to rectangle blinking

Comment: when I pass the PHP variable to the lat_center and lon_center than the particular marker border is not blinking....?

Comment: It doesn't sound related with the original question. Perhaps you should create a new one with the specific problem that arose.

Comment: Hi amen, please check the code i have added the new code of php and also google maps code ....please check

Comment: I'm sorry, but the new code is completely unrelated to the original question. I don't even understand what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Hi amen ,I will explain through the ajax call the javascript variable is pass then here in the second page i.e. blink_php.php page converted javascript variable to php variable through html to javscript variable passed to the Lat_center and long_center so that  it will plot in the maps

Comment: Hi amen, please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167295/added-the-svg-code-in-google-maps-and-blinking-is-not-displaying-in-google-map-w

Comment: I have Update my Code and Data with readable format ...please check